# Rails respond_to format - .js extension required?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, routes, heroku

I am capturing link click events and forwarding them via ajax, specifically jquery's getScript.

In development everything works fine with regard to respond to format

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {
    #by default renders show.html.haml 
  }
  format.js {
    #by default renders show.js.erb
  }
end
```

This behaviour somehow isn't taking place in production on heroku and the html file is always returned. If I add the file extension and define format recognition to the route then this works ok, however I thought this wasn't necessary?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To narrow this down I would compare the HTTP request and response headers for your getScript request in development and production. Pay attention to the Accept for request and the Content-Type for the response. Are they different?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Only difference is the response header's, dev text/javascript and production text/html.

Comment: Maybe log the request header in the action before respond_to?

Comment: Thanks fullware. It turns out it was something else as explained in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone comes across this I'll explain what I was doing wrong.

I'm making use of heroku's implementation of varnish to speed up an application. What happens is a previously generated dynamic webpage is downloaded from varnish then javascript calls home to the same url to check for page updates. This improves page response times considerably at the expense of non-js users and search engines potentially viewing slightly stale content.

It appears varnish doesn't distinguish between accepts headers and I was returned the previously cached html. To resolve this I've simply  added a time stamp param to the ajax request.

Comment: Of course! This is why I disagree with the axiom of "URI Opacity". Caches often do next respect HTTP headers. Rather than disabling caches entirely, that means you have to either add a suffix (i.e. .js) to the URI, or add a query param. This also comes up when you access a URI both as a standard HTTP request and as XHR.